# How to get all words over a specified length from a string?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I am writing a text analysis program for an assignment and need to write a function which will return all words over a specified length from a string (in this case all words with over 6 characters).

I have found plenty of examples which show how to return groups of words based on their lengths but none on how to get ALL the words over a specified length

Comment: So you say it's homework, have you even attempted anything?

Comment: The rest of the program is finished and pretty nicely written but every so often I still get baffled by little things like this

Comment: So you can at least make an attempt, the point of howework is to learn by mistake. Instead you just basically cheated.

Comment: Is `down-vote` two words or a single word?

Comment: Can't answer that one shiplu, apparently it would be cheating ;-)

Comment: @SliverNinja - Please don't add the homework tag, it's obsolete. I removed it for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static IEnumerable<string> getWordsWithMinLength(string text, int minLength)
{
    string[] words = text.Split();
    return words.Where(w => w.Length >= minLength);
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Choosing this as my accepted answer for pure cleaness. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
String [] words = text.Split(new char[] {' '},  
    System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
String [] filteredWords = words.Where(w => w.Length>6).ToArray();
```

Comment: This will treat `#$%$%$#%$#%$` as a word.

Comment: If someone writes it intentionally, why it shouldn't be word?

Comment: For the same reason why `on-line` shouldn't be a word.

Comment: `on-line` should not be treated as *two words*.

Comment: Says who? Definitely not OP, he didn't say anything. As far as everyone else is concerned, your word is as good as anyone else's.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of strings `var list = new List<string>()`,

loop through every word in your text,

`if (word.Length > 6) { list.Add(word) }`,

and when you're done, `return list;`

Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

At least you used the homework tag, this does scream "hey, do my work for me."  What have you tried so far?  Where are you having problems?

Break the problem down.  It seems like you have 3 logical pieces:

1)From a string, get all words

2)From those words, find all that have a length greater than N

3)Return those words.

Check out String.Split() for #1, and .Where() in Linq to do the filtering.

Comment: How does it not scream do my homework for me, the OP didn't even attempt it. The OP got frustrated because googling didn't give them the exact answer.

Comment: How do you know he didn't attempt it?

Comment: @AlexanderNikolasKantaris, there's nothing wrong with learning from others but you just had all the work done for you. There's a difference.